# sudo npm install webpack -g (failed)

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm-install

Run `sudo npm install webpack -g`, the message shows it works.

 When I type `webpack -v`, shows"webpack: command not found".

 Node version: `10.15.3`

**Command**:

> node install

**Output**:

```sh
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib' 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/userfile/.node-gyp/10.15.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/userfile/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ webpack@4.32.2
added 750 packages from 951 contributors in 246.511
```

Comment: You shuldn't need to use sudo even if it's global. You can use `--unsafe-perm` flag like this `npm install webpack -g --unsafe-perm`

Comment: There is a warning:checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/userfile/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 1):

You've got an `EACCESS` error, which means that your npm needs more permissions to work correctly.
To grant more rights to npm use this command => `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /your/path/to/node_modules`. 
If it's not working add also => `sudo chmod -R 755 /your/path/to`.
It should allows you to use npm w/ `sudo`.

If you want to do it with another way, here's an article from [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).